# How to change the button color when the button is press?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a button that has an orange background. But on pressing the button the colour does not remain the same. It changes to its default colour. And on release of button I get back the same colour. Is it possible to change the colour of the button while the button is being pressed?

My code is:

```
b = Button(frame1, text='Quit', command=quit_func)
b.grid(row=6,column=4,pady=5,padx=10)            
b.config( background="darkorange1", foreground="white")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` widget takes `activebackground` and `activeforeground` as parameters.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text='Quit', command="")
b.grid(row=6,column=4,pady=5,padx=10)
b.config(background="darkorange1", foreground="white",
         activebackground="darkorange1", activeforeground="white")

root.mainloop()
```

For a full list of button widget options, you can read it up [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method).