# Convert Tuple to Text in the for cycle creating labels

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm new to Programming and I want to study Python.
I have the following task:
Create from a tupla or list a matrix (window with tkinter) with label for every object in the tupla with the same "name" of the object.

```
import tkinter as tk

cards = ("AA", "AKs", "AQs", "AJs", "ATs", "A9s", "A8s", "A7s", "A6s", "A5s", "A4s", "A3s", "A2s", "AKo", "KK", "KQs")

root = tk.Tk()

for i in carte:
    label = tk.Label(root, **text = cards()** , bg="black", fg="white")


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. cards is a `Tuple`,you use `cards()`,that's incorrect.
2. `for i in carte` has spelling error.
3. after you create variable `label`,you haven't used `pack()`,`place()` or `grid()` to put it in your app.

Now the code might should be :

```
import tkinter as tk

cards = ("AA", "AKs", "AQs", "AJs", "ATs", "A9s", "A8s", "A7s", "A6s", "A5s", "A4s", "A3s", "A2s", "AKo", "KK", "KQs")

root = tk.Tk()

for i in cards:
    label = tk.Label(root, text = i , bg="black", fg="white")
    label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how can I change the color of AA label when a button is clicked?

Comment: @Fede Maybe you should read about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334628/how-to-change-the-button-color-when-the-button-is-press).If it isn't your expectation,you can search some key words in Stack Overflow.It must have the answer you expected.